# SSRS Report, Summing an Expression Column Contained in a Row Group

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report

I have a situation that I am struggling to figure out.  I have a report containing a table with 2 row groups.  The dataset comes from a SQL view.
Material Type is the first row group and Material Width is the child/second.  Drilling deeper I have some expressions calculating "linear feet in production" and finally "Tons of Material".  The row group will show linear feet and tons of material for each material width contained within a material type.
I need to get a sum total of the tons of material for each of the each material types (adding up the tonnage per different widths within the material type).  Below is my expression that calculates the tons of material.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am banging my head.  Its possible I have not provided enough information so please ask for more clarification if needed. Thanks in advance to anyone that may take a look.

```
=
(
((Fields!MATLDENSITY.Value)/2000)
*
(Sum(CDbl(Fields!USCATVLS_4.Value))*Fields!Quantity.Value)
*
((CDbl(Fields!USCATVLS_5.Value)/12)
*
(Fields!MATLTHICKNESS.Value/12)
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a tablix with 2 row groups. You have an expression that works on the inner group, but you need to sum the results of that.

What you need to do is specify the scope of your expression (the scope will be you inner row group) and then sum the results of this.

Taking a simple generic example...

If you have an expression in the inner group (`myInnerGrp`) that looks like this

```
=SUM(Fields!qty.Value * Fields!cost.Value)
```

As the scope is not specified in the expression above the current scope is used, this is the equivalent to specifying the scope as...

```
=SUM(Fields!qty.Value * Fields!cost.Value, "myInnerGroup")
```

So, if you want to sum the results of this in out outer group, the expression would be

```
=SUM(SUM(Fields!qty.Value * Fields!cost.Value, "myInnerGroup"))
```

Comment: Alan,
Thank you for the response.  I was not aware you could qualify the scope like that.  I am however still having issues with this.  By doing as you recommend, I end up with some really odd values in that cell.  If you take a look at the code box above you will see the expression contained in "Textbox65".  This correctly calculates the tonnage of material for each width but summing them does not.  Is there a way to call the value of that "Textbox65" without having to retype that entire expression adding the sum and scope?

Comment: You should be able to do `=SUM(ReportItems!Textbox65.Value)` . There are some restrictions on using this but rather than go into those, just try it first.

Comment: The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox4.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.

Comment: OK, so you will have to repeat the expression with the scope. I suggest you start by adding the scoped version (without the outer `SUM()` ) along side you current expression (in the same row group). You have to add the scope argument to all aggregates . Once you get the same results from both expressions then you can move it to the correct group and add the outer `SUM()`

Comment: Alan,
Thanks again for your response.  I cannot seem to figure this out.  SSRS complains about there being a missing ')'.  In your example above you show an extra closing parenthesis without an opening.  Is this correct?  It seems without adding that outer SUM it just doesn't like this at all and I am too inexperienced to understand what is going on here.

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the answer and removed the erroneous `)`

If you can post a sample of your data (as text or even better as a sql fiddle) and then a screen shot of the current and expected output based on that sample data I will try to give a more specific answer.